# Scalar curvature $K(p)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, stokes-theorem

> Prove that the scalar curvature $K(p)$ at $p \in M$ is given by 
>   $$
> K(p) = \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Ric}_p(x) dS^{n-1},
> $$
>   where $\omega_{n-1}$ is the area of the sphere $S^{n-1}$ in $T_pM$ and $dS^{n-1}$ is the area elements on $S^{n-1}$.

This is Exercise 4.9 of Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo.

> *Hint:* Use the following general argument on quadratic forms. Consider an orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ in $T_pM$ such that if $x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_ie_i$,
>   $$
> \text{Ric}_p(x)=\sum_i \lambda_i x_i^2, \quad \lambda_i \text{ real}.
> $$
>   Because $|x|=1$, the vector $\nu = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is a unit normal vector on $S^{n-1}$. Denoting $V=(\lambda_1 x_1,\ldots,\lambda_n x_n)$, and using Stokes Theorem, we obtain
>   \begin{align}
> \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \sum_i \lambda_i x_i^2 dS^{n-1} &= \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \langle V,\nu \rangle dS^{n-1} \\ 
> &= \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{B^n} \text{div} V dB^n,
> \end{align}
>   where $B^n$ is the unit ball whose boundary is $S^{n-1}=\partial B^n$. Noting that $\frac{\text{vol} B^n}{\omega_n}=\frac 1n$, we conclude that
>   \begin{align}
> \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Ric}_p(x) dS^{n-1} &= \frac 1n \text{div}V=\frac{\sum_i \lambda_i}n \\ 
> &= \frac{\sum_i \text{Ric}_p(e_i)}n = K(p).
> \end{align}

I was able to successfully provide details to every equality established in the hint except one. So my only question from all this is the justification of the equality
$$
\frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Ric}_p(x) dS^{n-1} = \frac 1n \text{div}V.
$$
What I have so far:
\begin{align}
\frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \text{Ric}_p(x) dS^{n-1} &= \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{S^{n-1}} \sum_i \lambda_i x_i^2 dS^{n-1} \\ 
&= \frac 1{\omega_{n-1}} \int_{B^n} \text{div} V dB^n \\ 
&= \frac {\text{div} V}{\omega_{n-1}}  \int_{B^n} dB^n \quad (?) \\ 
&= \frac {\text{div} V}{\omega_{n-1}}  \text{vol} B^n 
\end{align}
and after that I wanted to use $\frac{\text{vol} B^n}{\omega_n}=\frac 1n$ but what was confusing me is that I essentially have $\frac 1{\omega_{n-1}}$, not $\frac 1{\omega_n}$. Also, would I be able to (and, if so, should I?) pull $\text{div} V = \sum_i \lambda_i$ out of the integral?

Comment: Mikhail is correct, the correct relationship should be stated as $\mathrm{vol}B^n/\omega_{n-1}=1/n$. Also, you can (and should) certainly pull $\mathrm{div}V$ out of the integral... once you have diagonalized the quadratic form determined by Ricci curvature tensor you have that the $\lambda_i$ are constants (they vary as you move along the manifold, but they are constant in each tangent space)

Comment: Here is the original problem from do Carmo (https://www.docdroid.net/N4r6sDt). Are you saying that the relation $\frac{\text{vol} B^n}{\omega_n}=\frac 1n$ (Page 108, Line 2) is a typo? I thought this worked for the case of $n=3$ (and with $r=1$, because here $B^n$ is a unit ball): $$\frac{\text{vol} B^n}{\omega_n}=\frac{\text{vol} B^3}{\omega_3}=\frac{\frac 43 \pi}{4\pi} = \frac 13 = \frac 1n$$

Comment: I think it's a small typo. Note that do Carmo wrote that $\partial B^n = S^{n-1}$, and so if $\omega_{n-1}$ is the surface area of the $S^{n-1}$ you see that in the case of $n=3$ that $\mathrm{vol}B^3 = 4/3\pi$ and $\omega_{n-1}=\omega_2=4\pi$ is the surface area of the 2-sphere embedded in 3-dimensional space. I think the issue/confusion might be coming from the fact that $n$ in $B^n$ and $S^{n-1}$ denotes the dimension of the respective manifold, and not the dimension of the ambient space.

Comment: Take a look at the volume and surface area formulas here as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Volume_and_surface_area . You get the correct relationship once you note that $\Gamma(n/2)/\Gamma(n/2+1)=2/n$.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. It's $\omega_2=4\pi$, like you said, because $\partial B^3=S^2$ is a manifold of dimension $2$. In general, for unit balls $B^n$ with surface area $\omega_{n-1}$, $$\frac{\text{vol} B^n}{\omega_{n-1}}=\frac{\frac{\pi^{\frac n2}}{\Gamma(\frac n2+1)}}{\frac{2\pi^{\frac n2}}{\Gamma(\frac n2)}}=\frac 12 \frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{\Gamma(\frac n2+1)}=\frac 12 \frac 2n=\frac 1n,$$ where the equality $\frac{\Gamma(\frac n2)}{\Gamma(\frac n2+1)}=\frac 2n$ invokes the identity of $\Gamma(a+1)=a\Gamma(a)$ with $a:=\frac n2$.

Comment: Great, I'm glad that's cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

Volume of the ball is the integral of the area of the sphere, and the factor $\frac{1}{n}$ comes from integration.

Comment: NO! Concentric spheres have area proportional to $r^{n-1}$. @Newdayrising